# FIiter Out the Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have List List courseTakenList.i want to filter out the Status which are in `Completed,Dropped,Current,Schudeled`. Here is the code sample.

```
courseTakenList = (from courseTaken in courseTakenList
                      select new Course
                      {
                           Status = "Scheduled"?"COMPLETE"?"Dropped"? "Current"
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: It is not clear, how you want the status to be chosen

Comment: Status should be chossen between these values.there are so many for satatus.But i want the linq query which will return me these status in List.

Comment: If `courseTakenList` contains courses with different statuses and you need to choose only courses with **these** statuses, then Pranay Rana has already answered this. If this is wrong, I still do not understand, what you need...

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted answer if it works for you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it even more concise

```
var statuslist= {"Completed","Dropped","Current","Schudeled"};

var courses = courseTakenList.Where(courseTaken => 
                       statuslist.Contains(courseTaken.Status);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Linq In` query like this will resolve your issue

```
var statuslist= {"Completed","Dropped","Current","Schudeled"};

var query = from courseTaken in courseTakenList
            where statuslist.Contains( courseTaken .Status )
            select courseTaken ;
```

**Note** : change select clause as you want

Comment: Thanks,but i wanted to put filter while selecting the like   courseTakenList = (from courseTaken in courseTakenList
                                  select new Course
                                  {
                                      DegreeAudit = degreeAudit,
                                      
                                      Id = courseTaken.CourseId,Status = "Scheduled"?"COMPLETE"?"Dropped"? "Current"

Comment: @KCS why do you need to create new instances of `Course`, while it is enough just to select them from the original `courseTakenList`?

Comment: @KCS - filter you can apply in where clause and your status field going to conation one of the value.....try out the query of answer might work for you..because not clear what you want to do

Comment: Thanks Pranya,Your answer is perfect.